# HTTP Polling vs Durable Functions Monitoring in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Is there a sweet spot between polling an endpoint with policy and using the Monitoring pattern with Durable Functions? I'll use a slightly modified Monitoring example from the [Azure Durable Functions docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview#pattern-4-monitoring) to illustrate. In example below, a configurable amount of seconds are used to wait in between checks. In addition, there is overhead for the durable function to checkpoint and replay.

```
public static async Task Run(DurableOrchestrationContext ctx) {
    int jobId = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<string>("StartJob", ctx.GetInput<MyData>());
    int pollingInterval = GetPollingInterval();
    DateTime expiryTime = GetExpiryTime();

    while (ctx.CurrentUtcDateTime < expiryTime) {
        var jobStatus = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<string>("GetJobStatus", jobId);
        if (jobStatus == "Completed") {
            await ctx.CallActivityAsync("SendAlert", machineId);
            break;
        }
        var nextCheck = ctx.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddSeconds(pollingInterval);
        await ctx.CreateTimer(nextCheck, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

If the asynchronous job that gets kicked off in the StartJob activity usually executes within a second or two, would it really be worth adding this overhead for checkpoint and replay in, as opposed to polling in the StartJob activity with some type of backoff policy?